# Using NDDE in VB.net How to trap Error correctly?

Tags: vb.net, ndde

I am using NDDE in my application using the following code

```
Public WithEvents DXViewDDE As New NDde.Client.DdeClient("DXView", "DDEServer", DDEClient)
Case DXViewServer
                If Not DXViewDDE.IsConnected Then
                    Try
                        DXViewDDE.Connect() 'Here it throws an unhandled error
                        AddHandler DXViewDDE.Disconnected, AddressOf DXViewDDEOnDisconnected
                        DXViewDDE.StartAdvise("SpotPrefix", 1, True, 60000)
                        DXViewDDE.StartAdvise("DDECommand", 1, True, 60000)
                        DDEClient.SpotPrefix.Text = DXViewDDE.Request("SpotPrefix", 60000)
                        DDEClient.DDELookup.Text = DXViewDDE.Request("DDECommand", 60000)
                        SetServerConnected(theServer, DXViewDDE.IsConnected)
                    Catch
                        SetServerConnected(theServer, False)
                    End Try
                End If
```

If the server that this routine is running it connects correctly and proceeds but if the server is off line I get the following error
!(http:www.n2amg.com/DDEError.jpg)

2 questions.. Why is the Try/Catch not picking this up?? and how can I program to trap this error if the server is not online so it can continue to run the rest of the routines after this??

Thanks in advance
Rick

Comment: Did you try debbuging your code line by line in order to know exaclty wich line throws the error? because this is not an exception `(http:www.n2amg.com/DDEError.jpg)`

Comment: Yes I did It happens on the DXViewDDE.Connect. since the server is not running it causes the error. I need to trap that error so it will continue on.

Comment: can you edit your question in order to add a comment on the line that throws the error? this will be usefull for future users ;) comments are automatically deleted after a while

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declare a function to handle unhandled errors like shown below:

***First***: create your own function to handle the error

```
    Private Sub UnExHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        'Do your stuff
    End Sub
```

***Second:*** add the Handler on the code:

```
Public WithEvents DXViewDDE As New NDde.Client.DdeClient("DXView", "DDEServer", DDEClient)
    AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnExHandler
    'Your things
    RemoveHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnExHandler
```

***N.B.*** Don't forget to remove the handler!

***Remarks***

This will catch every exception that is unhandled by the code. It must catch your error!

Comment: This does not seem to work my  Public WithEvents is in to top declaration and the routine I posted is part of a routine that tries to connect to the servers. Placing these where the withevents are causes an error and adding the addhandlers in the routine does the same.

Comment: Rick probably the error isn't thrown inside your vb.net code but inside your NDDE application inside the server (I come up with this thinking how could be an error a jpg inside the server)

Comment: I posted the image to show what is coming up its just a screenshot of the error that pops up. I took a screenshot and cut it down to size. the popup is the error window that shows after the connect tries to take place.

Comment: I guess this one is going to be a tough one. In the development environment I get the error but If I run the .exe file it works as it should and causes no error's at all.

Comment: What? At this point i think that my answer is pretty useless for your problem. But I will leave it there. Maybe it will help other users